# Ember JS Index routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Can someone better explain with is going on with the implied index route and controllers in Ember JS?

See this example, why is the behavior different in these two examples?

Index route explicitly defined

http://jsbin.com/ILAP/1/

The index route is implied

http://jsbin.com/ILAP/2/

What is confusing to me is why the nesting behavior works in the second example but not the first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the students/student route structure:

```
students
----index
----student
--------index
```

First case

> Index route explicitly defined

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="students">
  {{ outlet }}
</script>    

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="students/index">  
  ... omitted ...
  <div class="well">
    Expecting to render student template here:
    <br />
    {{ outlet }}
  </div>

</script>  

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="student">
  <h2>Student</h2>
  <h3>{{name}}</h3>
  <h4>{{grade}}</h4>
  <h4>{{gpa}}</h4>
</script>
```

When you make a transition to `student.index`, first is appended the `student` template and after `student/index`. Because you dont have override the default conventions, via `renderTemplate`. The place where the template is rendered, is into the main outlet (an outlet without name) aka `{{outlet}}`, of the parent route template. So `student` template will be inserted in the `students` main outlet. Not `students/index`, because it's the sibling. This is the reason why all your content is replaced. And the `student/index` will be inserted in `student`

Second case

> The index route is implied

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="students">
  ... omitted ...
  <div class="well">
    Expecting to render student template here:
    <br />
    {{ outlet }}
  </div>

</script>  

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="student">
  <h2>Student</h2>
  <h3>{{name}}</h3>
  <h4>{{grade}}</h4>
  <h4>{{gpa}}</h4>
</script>
```

This time, like the previous sample, the resolution of the templates don't change. But this time we don't have the `student/index`. So first is rendered the `student` in `students` outlet, after because the `student/index` is missing, it's is ignored. The final result is the template where you expect.

**Summary**

Using the default conventions. Templates will be rendered in the parent, not sibling, parent route template.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. That helps! So index template is really optional. And the point about siblings makes sense.